# All-to-All thread communication in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, communication, pipe

Thanks for your attention

I am writing a simulation engine in python using "threading" module in python. One of the things that my simulator has to do is to be able to do all-to-all communication. Suppose there are 'n' threads (All n-threads are not instances of the same class).

So for example I have 3 classes of threads

- m is an instance of class type 'Storage'
- s is an instance of class type 'Super'
- c1, c2... cn are instances of class type 'Child'

m, s, c1, c2, ... cn might have to communicate with each other 1:1. Is it wise to maintain a one-to-one connection with each other ? My solution is to build an arbiter thread which will accept messages and route them to the target thread. That way, I will have fewer pipes going around. Do you think this is a good idea ?

Is there a readymade python module/solution that can do this kind of arbitration ?

RRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution of a broadcast `Queue`, and `EventBus` thread is the most common pattern. `Queue` is part of standard library, and a thread that consumes singleton queue and broadcasts to registered consumers is trivial to implement.

Alternatively you could link those threads to form a cycle and pass message to the successor, ignoring messages originating from self.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at the "candygram" message passing extension.